# Why won't my raytracer recreate the "mount" scene?

Tags: graphics, raytracing

I'm trying to render the "mount" scene from [Eric Haines' Standard Procedural Database (SPD)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150510022649/http://tog.acm.org/resources/SPD/overview.html), but the refraction part just doesn't want to co-operate. I've tried everything I can think of to fix it.

This one is my render (with Watt's formula):

[image: My render.]
<sub>(source: [philosoraptor.co.za](http://www.philosoraptor.co.za/programming/SPD/mount_mine.png))</sub>

This is my render using the "normal" formula:

[image: Normal formula.]
<sub>(source: [philosoraptor.co.za](http://www.philosoraptor.co.za/programming/SPD/mount_mine_normal.png))</sub>

And this one is the correct render:

[image: Correct render.]
<sub>(source: [philosoraptor.co.za](http://www.philosoraptor.co.za/programming/SPD/mount_haines.png))</sub>

As you can see, there are only a couple of errors, mostly around the poles of the spheres. This makes me think that refraction, or some precision error is to blame.

Please note that there are actually 4 spheres in the scene, their NFF definitions (`s x_coord y_coord z_coord radius`) are:

```
s -0.8 0.8 1.20821 0.17
s -0.661196 0.661196 0.930598 0.17
s -0.749194 0.98961 0.930598 0.17
s -0.98961 0.749194 0.930598 0.17
```

That is, there is a fourth sphere behind the more obvious three in the foreground. It can be seen in the gap left between these three spheres.

Here is a picture of that fourth sphere alone:

[image: 'Fourth' sphere.]
<sub>(source: [philosoraptor.co.za](http://www.philosoraptor.co.za/programming/SPD/mount_sphere_2.png))</sub>

And here is a picture of the first sphere alone:

[image: 'First' sphere.]
<sub>(source: [philosoraptor.co.za](http://www.philosoraptor.co.za/programming/SPD/mount_sphere_1.png))</sub>

You'll notice that many of the oddities present in both my version and the correct version is missing. We can conclude that these effects are the result of interactions between the spheres, the question is which interactions?

What am I doing wrong? Below are some of the potential errors I've already considered:

- **Refraction vector formula.**

As far as I can tell, this is correct. It's the same formula used by several websites and I verified the derivation personally. Here's how I calculate it:

<strike>`double sinI2 = eta * eta * (1.0f - cosI * cosI);`</strike>

`Vector transmit = (v * eta) + (n * (eta * cosI - sqrt(1.0f - sinI2)));`

`transmit = transmit.normalise();`

I found an alternate formula in 3D Computer Graphics, 3rd Ed by Alan Watt. It gives a closer approximation to the correct image:

```
double etaSq = eta * eta;
double sinI2 = etaSq * (1.0f - cosI * cosI);
Vector transmit = (v * eta) + (n * (eta * cosI - (sqrt(1.0f - sinI2) / etaSq)));
transmit = transmit.normalise();
```

The only difference is that I'm dividing by eta^2 at the end.

- **Total internal reflection.**

I tested for this, using the following conditional before the rest of my intersection code:

```
if (sinI2 <= 1)
```

- **Calculation of eta.**

I use a stack-like approach for this problem:

```
        /* Entering object. */
        if (r.normal.dot(r.dir) < 0)
        {
           double eta1 = r.iorStack.back();
           double eta2 = m.ior;
           eta = eta1 / eta2;

           r.iorStack.push_back(eta2);
        }
        /* Exiting object. */
        else
        {
           double eta1 = r.iorStack.back();
           r.iorStack.pop_back();
           double eta2 = r.iorStack.back();

           eta = eta1 / eta2;
        }
```

As you can see, this stores the previous objects that contained this ray in a stack. When exiting the code pops the current IOR off the stack and uses that, along with the IOR under it to compute eta. As far as I know this is the most correct way to do it.

This works for nested transmitting objects. However, it breaks down for *intersecting* transmitting objects. The problem here is that you need to define the IOR for the intersection independently, which the NFF file format does not do. It's unclear then, what the "correct" course of action is.

- **Moving the new ray's origin.**

The new ray's origin has to be moved slightly along the transmitted path so that it doesn't intersect at the same point as the previous one.

```
p = r.intersection + transmit * 0.0001f;
```

<strike>`p += transmit * 0.01f;`</strike>

<strike>I've tried making this value smaller (0.001f) and (0.0001f) but that makes the spheres appear solid. I guess these values don't move the rays far enough away from the previous intersection point.</strike>

EDIT: The problem here was that the reflection code was doing the same thing. So when an object is reflective as well as refractive then the origin of the ray ends up in completely the wrong place.

- **Amount of ray bounces.**

I've artificially limited the amount of ray bounces to 4. I tested raising this limit to 10, but that didn't fix the problem.

- **Normals.**

I'm pretty sure I'm calculating the normals of the spheres correctly. I take the intersection point, subtract the centre of the sphere and divide by the radius.

Comment: I don't know if it would help or not, since it's been about a year and a half since I've done ray tracing.  Is there cases where a ray should ever intersect more than twice?  If not, then you may be able to special case that and avoid having to deal with the recast offset.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean: when I intersect a sphere with a ray, I should check whether t0 == 0. If it is, then I should use t1. Then I don't have to move the intersection points at all?

Unless I misunderstand. What do you meant by "intersect more than twice", and "recast offset"?

Comment: images unavailable :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more than I year, I finally figured out what was going on here. Clear minds and all that. I was completely off track with the formula. I'm instead using a formula by Heckbert now, which I am sure is correct because I proved it myself using geometry and discrete math.

Here's the correct vector calculation:

```
double c1 = v.dot(n) * -1;
double c1Sq = pow(c1, 2);

/* Heckbert's formula requires eta to be eta2 / eta1, so I have to flip it here. */
eta = 1 / eta;
double etaSq = pow(eta, 2);

if (etaSq + c1Sq >= 1)
{
   Vector transmit = (v / eta) + (n / eta) * (c1 - sqrt(etaSq - 1 + c1Sq));
   transmit = transmit.normalise();
...
}
else
{
   /* Total internal reflection. */
}
```

In the code above, eta is eta1 (the IOR of the surface from which the ray is coming) over eta2 (the IOR of the destination surface), v is the incident ray and n is the normal.

There was another problem, which confused the problem some more. I had to flip the *normal* when exiting an object (which is obvious - I missed it because the other errors were obscuring it).

Lastly, my line of sight algorithm (to determine whether a surface is illuminated by a point light source) was not properly passing through transparent surfaces.

So now my images line up properly :)

Comment: I'm having a ridiculously hard time with this. I don't know what the hell is going wrong - I copied refraction code line for line, from one of **my** previous raytracers, yet I get total internal reflection in my spheres, leading to a black outline. Using the Heckbert formula in your post gives the exact same results as the Snell algorithm, so that's not where the problem is, at least for me. I am also flipping the normal and drew like fifteen diagrams of every possible case - *sigh*. You must have fixed something else somewhere. I guess I'll get it fixed in 2015, lol.

Comment: Did you post a question? Also, are you sure you're calculating eta correctly?

Comment: No, didn't post a question yet. I think I am calculating eta right, basically deciding whether the ray is inside the sphere or outside (by comparing its dot product with the normal) and choosing n1 and n2 correctly, as well as flipping the normal if the ray is inside the sphere. I think it's because I was trying to shoehorn it into my BRDF class - I really should make it a BTDF instead since it can transmit. But it worked before.. so..

Comment: And you flip the normal _after_ checking for eta? Also, you do move the ray after the intersection? Not doing that can also cause your problem.

Comment: No, I do it at the same time (i.e. select n1, n2 according to the sign of the dot product of the incident ray and the original normal, flipping the normal if the incident ray is "inside" - then calculating eta) [I need to keep n1 and n2 around since I'm calculating Fresnel reflectance a few lines later]. I do move the ray by an epsilon in the right direction. My code works in OpenCL but not in Python, I'm leaning towards me being stupid with the language and overlooking something.

Comment: Could be. Python has a number of gotchas w.r.t. floating point values.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess based on doing a image diff (and without reading the rest of your question). The problem looks to me to be the refraction on the back side of the sphere. You might be:

- doing it backwards: e.g. reversing (or not reversing) the indexes of refraction.
- missing it entirely?

One way to check for this would be to look at the mount through a cube that is almost facing the camera. If the refraction is correct, the picture should be offset slightly but otherwise un-altered. If it's not right, then the picture will seem slightly tilted.

Comment: I tested, and I'm not missing the back of the sphere. I have code for handling back faces and inserting a print there issues scores of lines of output.

I'm also sure that I'm computing eta correctly, the code I use is in my question. I've updated this code somewhat to use a stack of IOR values since posting it.

I'll try looking at the mountain using a polygon, unfortunately I didn't implement cubes. Perhaps I could try two parallel planes?

Comment: @fluffels I think BCS has a good point... looking at the first image and the correct image, the correct image shows the mountains bulging out as the effect of refraction, whereas your first image shows them puckering in. I'm sure you can see this but your comment "there are only a couple of errors, mostly around the poles" seems to miss this difference. It sure looks like something is reversed, but I have no clue what. (Also I don't understand the 4th sphere ... is it supposed to be in front of the others or behind?)

Comment: @fluffels, two parallel plains would work: render with them an without them and check that the image just shifts slightly. Also be sure you have them pointing away from each other and not in the same direction. I've looked at the eta computation you posted and it seems to asymmetric. I would expect the code for entry and exit to be almost identical, maybe with just two terms swapped from one to the other.

Comment: @LarsH I added some more images that hopefully explain the nature of the scene.

Comment: @LarsH I get what you mean about that distortion. But I don't know what to do about it. I've tried flipping normals, eta values, everything.

Comment: @BCS Eta's calculation will be symmetric only if the ray is entering an object and then leaving it again. When objects start being included in each other and intersecting (as the 'extra' sphere in this scene does) then things get more complicated. AFAIK eta = eta1 / eta2 where eta1 is the IOR of the "from" substance and eta2 is the IOR of the "to" substance.

Comment: @BCS The problem with the parallel planes is that NFF only supports one-sided polygons, so I can't make it point away from me - the way the algorithm works in this program will not see that as an intersection. I'll try with two polygons looking at me and see if that's in any way illuminating.

Comment: @fluffels: re eta: Your comment leads me to believe that it *should* be symmetric: compute `eta1` for the object you are at the surface of, compute `eta2` for the surrounding object: `eta = !Entering ? (eta1/eta2) : (eta2/eta1)` (this gives a corner case for non-point coincident surfaces).

Comment: As far as I understand refraction, eta1 and eta2 should be swapped around in your formula. Why do you believe it should be symmetric? If a ray is travelling through a sphere with an IOR of 1.3 and enters one with an IOR of 1.5 then eta = 1.3 / 1.5 where it was 1.0 / 1.3 previously when the ray entered the first sphere. Or is this not correct?

Comment: @Fluffels: The symmetric bit is in the general equations, not the specific values. For a ray travailing from a sphere with 1.3 and exiting into a sphere with 1.5, eta is 1.3/1.5 i.e. `A/B` for `A` = the IOR of the object who's surface we are intersecting and `B` = the IOR of the "other" object. For the other case, entering the same sphere, from air: eta is `1/1.3`, i.e. `B/A` with A and B similarly defined (B in the 1st case is another sphere and in the 2nd air). Keep in mind that this will give very strange results if you have two or more intersecting surfaces of solids with `IOR_a!=IOR_b`.